# Android Studio Emulator: Device is not Play Protect certified

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, qemu, google-play-protect

I just migrated from Windows to macOS and downloaded Android Lollipop 5.0 ARM emulator with Google API. When I run one of my project that is using some Google Services I get this notification which is new to me. What is the exact meaning of this and will it cause any functionality problem with my project during testing? As of now I am not able to pass recaptcha with Firebase Phone Auth.

[image]

Comment: Before a new device or firmware is release it has to pass a certification test suite developed by Google. Google collects the results and saves each device profile in a large database. Only those devices are allowed to come with Google apps and services installed. Emulators don't get such a certification (may be except the Google API emulator images for the Android Studio emulator).

Comment: @Robert the image I am using here has Google API, there is also sometimes another type of image called Google Play but only available on newer SDK. However, in my last daily driver (Windows) this notification never show.